# Не работает фокус на форме

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю в чем ошибка при фокусе. Должно обращаться к форме и выделяться но не работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .focused {
        outline: solid 2px red;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="formElement">
      One: <input type="text" /><br /><br />
      Two: <input type="text" />
    </form>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var formElement = document.forms["formElement"];
      
      formElement.onfocus = function () {


        if (this.classList.contains('focused')) {
          this.classList.remove('focused');
        }
      
      };

      formElement.onblur = function () {
        if (!formElement.value.includes(' ')) { 
          input.classList.add('focused');

        }
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ошибка во всем.

Comment: возможно, но как исправить так чтобы Input выделялся?

Comment: Никак исправить. Изучить документацию и написать заново.

Comment: допустим, но как обратиться внутри формы к импутам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был "в чем ошибка"

Ответ: проблема в том что событие focus не всплывает

Смотрим документацию:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event
Видим : Bubbles NO

Смотрим тут:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event
Видим : Bubbles Yes
Добавьте эти строчки вместо Вашего кода и посмотрите на результат.

```
 <script >
     var formElement = document.forms["formElement"];
     formElement.addEventListener("focusin",()=> {
        console.log("focusin");
      });
    
      formElement.addEventListener("focus",()=> {
        console.log("focus");
      });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот понял

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     formElement.addEventListener("focusin",(event)=> {
        event.target.classList.add('focused')
      });
    
      formElement.addEventListener("focusout",(event)=> {
        event.target.classList.remove('focused')
      });
    </script>
```